# How to save and retrieve pdf annotation using ios swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, annotations, urlretrieve

I just created a web view programatically to load pdf and added YPDrawSignatureView to draw signature in the pdf view..

I cant able to retrieve the drawn signature while reopening again in the web view

created using this ref link:
https://github.com/GJNilsen/YPDrawSignatureView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cant able to retrieve the drawn signature while reopening again in
>   the web view

There is a method in `YPDrawSignatureView` to let you export the new pdf data.

`public func getPDFSignature() -> Data`

You should save it when finish edited and present it again to the web view. You may have to save `Data` to your desired format.